# Change Theme of "New Password" screen

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm using Liferay 6.2.1 EE SP6/CE.
I've modified the password policies to enable:

```
passwords.default.policy.change.required=true
```

This forces new users to change the password on first login.

When user tries to login for the first time, the user is redirected to change his password as expected, but the theme is Classic.
I have a custom theme developed for my whole site.

**How can I apply this custom theme to the Change Password on first login - "New Password" screen?**

Tried the below properties to no effect:

```
default.regular.theme.id=mycustomtheme_WAR_mycustomtheme
default.user.public.layout.regular.theme.id=mycustomtheme_WAR_mycustomtheme
default.user.private.layout.regular.theme.id=mycustomtheme_WAR_mycustomtheme
```

Comment: The above three properties solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below portal property fixed it.

`default.user.private.layout.regular.theme.id=mycustomtheme_WAR_mycustomtheme`

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a default theme in:

```
Control Panel -> Configuration -> Portal Settings -> Display Settings -> Look and Feel -> Default Theme
```

Comment: Tried that earlier, Artem. No result. Correct me if I am wrong but the property `default.regular.theme.id=mycustomtheme_WAR_mycustomtheme` is to set the same thing.